# Unable to connect oracle database (12c) while installing informatica power center 9.5.1

Tags: informatica

Oracle environment:

- Guest OS: centos7 (Installed in a VMWARE)
- version:  Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production

Informatica Power Center:

- Downloaded site: https://edelivery.oracle.com/osdc/faces/SoftwareDelivery
- Software: Oracle Business Intelligence Data Warehouse Administration Console and Informatica PowerCenter
  version: 9.5.1
- Host OS: windows 10

While installing, informatica is asking to connect to the oracle user. So I created a user and granted dba to it. Even though I provided correct database address, Informatica test connection is failing.

But, with the same config details I can able to connect DB through SQL developer(Version: 19.2.0.206.2117) which was installed on windows (host OS).

Answer (score 0):

So many possibilities, sql developer is running on your local windows client picking up your local tnsnames.ora to resolve the db connection against and with firewalls opened between your local windows client and the database. On your centos server, the Informatica install will resolve against the tnsnames.ora there which may not have an entry for the sid you're trying to hit and even then it will also only find its local tnsnames.ora file if the user doing the install has ORACLE_HOME correctly set in their profile. Not to mention firewalls and networking between the centos machine and the db may not be open.